# Match newlines except if it ends with semicolon

Tags: regex

I want to match newline \n except when the line ends with semicolon. 
My attempt so far is (?!;\n)\n which matches newline but doesn't exclude anything. Sample text:

```
this is a line of text that should match
it should exclude this line;
this line should also be ignored;
but this should match
```

Comment: What is the language/regex flavor? Should it match empty lines?

Comment: I'm trying both vim and notepad++, not sure what flavors they match unfortunately. It should ignore empty lines as well but it's not important.

Comment: Vim and NPP regex flavors are rather different. Ok, I'd use Notepad++ with `\n(?<!;\n)` pattern.

Comment: That worked great Wiktor, thank you!

Comment: Maybe in Vim you can try `\n\(;\n\)\@<!`, please check.

Comment: Same result, it works just as wanted. Thank you for the fast replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To only match a `\n` not preceded with `;` in Notepad++, you can use

```
\n(?<!;\n)
```

or

```
(?<!;)\n
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aF8vO5/1)

The `(?<!...)` is a **look-behind** zero-width assertion that checks but does not consume the text that is immediately *before* the text we match (the `\n` symbol). You tried a *look-ahead* that checks the text right *after* the text you matched.

The same construct in Vim is `\(....\)\@<!`:

```
\n\(;\n\)\@<!
```

or

```
\(;\)\@<!\n
```

Answer (score 6):

use a negated character class

```
.*[^;]$
```

This matches the lines as the test data implies.  To match exactly the newline at the end of the line only as a capture

```
.*[^;](\n)
```

Here is a demo in perl showing this behaviour, assuming the testdata is in a file textdata.txt

```
perl -n -e 'print ord($1)."yes line $. $1" if /.*[^;](\n)/; ' nlmadness.txt 
10yes line 1 
10yes line 4
```

The "ord($1)" expression means convert the $1, the first match from a character to a numeric encoding.  On my system this is UTF-8 and newline matches to decimal ten

The $. is the line number

Comment: I just wonder how this regex can be helpful since the title says *Match **newlines***, not *lines*.

Comment: Just to clarify, I want to match the following newline and not the line of text itself.

Answer (score 1):

Bind it to the beginning and the end:

```
^(.*[^;]{1})$
# match everything from star to end (^ to $)
# the last character MUST NOT be a semicolon
# save the whole string in a capturing group
```

See [a demo here on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yR5eN3/1).

Comment: This regex is the same as Vorsprung's.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It is, haven't updated the answers before. Also it actually captures them instead of just matching, but the difference is rather academical, admittedly.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the regexp in this answer isn't *exactly* the same :)

Comment: @Vorsprung: I agree it is not the same, it has two unnecessary decorations compared to yours. Capture group is redundant since it is applied to the whole pattern (that we can refer to with `$0`) and `{1}` limiting quantifier is plain redundant as is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Always a pleasure to read your explaining comments :)

Comment: By saying "the same", I meant the two patterns match the same text.